# how to get text of span of perticular class

Tags: html

```
<a class="goog-te-menu2-item" href="javascript:void(0)">
<a class="goog-te-menu2-item" href="javascript:void(0)">
<a class="goog-te-menu2-item" href="javascript:void(0)">
<a class="goog-te-menu2-item-selected" href="javascript:void(0)">


    <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
        <span class="indicator">›</span>
         <span class="text">Chinese (Simplified)</span>
       </div>

</a>
<a class="goog-te-menu2-item" href="javascript:void(0)">
```

here there are multiple anchor tag inside that every anchor tag has class as a goog-te-menu2-item but  i need to take only the text of span that has class as a goog-te-menu2-item-selected.

THank You in advance

Comment: are you ok with jquery solutions??

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with jquery solutions use like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('goog-te-menu2-item-selected'))
    {
      alert($(this).find('.text').html());     
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello Suresh 
 THank u 4 quick reply but its not working at my end, it failed to take text of that selected span

Comment: yes its working ,but only for static class, but that  goog-te-menu2-item-selected class apply to that anchor tag, which i have selected. that class can b3 applied to anchor tag dynamically.

Comment: How can i detect which anchor tag has assigned that class?

Comment: which class? goog-te-menu2-item-selected??

Comment: yes, goog-te-menu2-item-selected, when i select perticular language then goog-te-menu2-item-selected this class applied to that anchor.

Comment: updated my answer. check it out. it will go through all the links one by one and find the selected class.